# Return CompletableFuture<List<String>> from CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<GetConnectedServicesResponse>>

Tags: lambda, java-8, completable-future

I have a method that returns a `CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<GetConnectedServicesResponse>>` object.

`GetConnectedServicesResponse` class has  an attribute `List<ConnectedService> connectedServices;`

`ConnectedService` class has an attribute  `String name;`

What I want to do is to write a method that returns a `CompletableFuture<List<String>>` where String is the `name` of every `ConnectedService`

I wrote the following method but I am struggling to finish it.

```
 private CompletableFuture<Optional<List<String>>> getConnectedServicesFromVpi(String vpi) {
    List<ConnectedService> connectedServices;
    connectedServiceFleetManagerClient.getConnectedServices(vpi)
            .thenApply(x -> x.payload())
            .thenApply(y -> y.map(x -> x.getConnectedServices()))
            .thenApply()

}
```

In the below image you can also see the objects types that I get from my implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to finish it with the following code.

```
 private CompletableFuture<List<String>> getConnectedServicesFromVpi(String vpi) {
    CompletableFuture<GetConnectedServicesResponse> getConnectedServicesResponseCompletableFuture =
            connectedServiceFleetManagerClient.getConnectedServices(vpi)
            .thenApply(x ->
                    x.payload().get());

    return getConnectedServicesResponseCompletableFuture.handle(this::handle); 
}

private List<String> handle (GetConnectedServicesResponse getConnectedServicesResponse, Throwable throwable) {
    return getConnectedServicesResponse
            .getConnectedServices()
            .stream()
            .map(ConnectedService::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```